# Create a .NET 5.0 Azure Function of the Service Bus Queue Flavor that uses Peek Lock Mode

Tags: c#, azure-functions

How can I create a .NET 5.0 Azure Function implementation of the Service Bus Queue Flavor that uses Peek Lock Mode?

I can get a Service Bus Function working fine with signatures like this:

```
    [Function("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("myfunction", Connection = "ServiceBusQueueConnection")] string fileContent, FunctionContext context)
```

But I don't know what a peek lock signature needs to look like though.

Comment: I was under the impression that Peek Lock Mode was the default?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Let me test and confirm...

Comment: Yep you are right.  All tested and seems to be the default behaviour.  Am I able to mark your comments as an answer?  Apologies I  rareley use SO so not sure how some of it works.

Comment: @Dave Amour To accept it as an answer click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Thomas Schmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449426/thomas-schmidt). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

"I was under the impression that Peek Lock Mode was the default? [PeekLock behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior)"